# SELECT AS STRUCT to json

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to turn a `STRUCT` into json in the `SELECT AS STRUCT` construction in json? For example:

```
WITH tbl AS (
    SELECT "val.num" AS field_path, "INT64" AS data_type UNION ALL
    SELECT "val.str", "STRING"
) SELECT AS STRUCT field_path, data_type FROM tbl
```

How could I get this into the `JSON` value `{"val.num": "INT64", "val.str": "STRING"}` ?

Comment: cold you check this?


WITH tbl AS (
  SELECT "val.num" AS field_path, "INT64" AS data_type UNION ALL
  SELECT "val.str", "STRING"
)
SELECT JSON_OBJECTAGG(field_path, data_type) AS json_value
FROM tbl;

Comment: @TowsifAhamedLabib I don't think BigQuery offers that -- it seems more a postgres thing. Here are the BQ json functions: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions

Comment: oh, sorry......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How could I get this into the JSON value {"val.num": "INT64", "val.str": "STRING"} ?

Not sure there is other way to do it without string manipulation. Anyway below might be one option you can use to generate your expected output.

I've implemented it in an UDF which takes `key-value pairs` as a parameter and returns `JSON` object.

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION kv2json (pairs ARRAY<STRUCT<k STRING, v STRING>>) AS ((
  SELECT PARSE_JSON(CONCAT('{"', STRING_AGG(k || '":"' || v, '","'), '"}'))
    FROM UNNEST(pairs)
));

WITH tbl AS (
  SELECT "val.num" AS field_path, "INT64" AS data_type UNION ALL
  SELECT "val.str", "STRING"
)
SELECT kv2json(ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(field_path, data_type)))
  FROM tbl;
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the simplest way would be to create an array of these pairs. For example:

```
WITH tbl AS (
    SELECT "val.num" AS field_path, "INT64" AS data_type UNION ALL
    SELECT "val.str", "STRING"
)
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT field_path, data_type FROM tbl)
```

And if you want to turn that into `json`, do it as `TO_JSON(ARRAY(...))`.

[image]

However, this is not in `k/v` form but an array of key-values. I'm not quite sure how to get that into a single k/v object.